# How to contribute failing test cases

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, open-source

I found a bug in an open source project on GitHub, and wrote a failing test for it, but haven't suggested a fix due to insufficient familiarity with the code.

How does one usually contribute such tests? Shall I create a pull request? Note that the continuous integration would fail for my commit as it adds a (currently) failing test..

(For reference here's [the actual test](https://github.com/construct/construct/pull/410))

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the "Issues" functionality of Git. Create an issue as a bug report, instead of creating a pull request.